# MySQL - Correct way to use the UNIQUE KEY?

Tags: mysql

Is the proper way to use the `UNIQUE KEY` in my MySQL table?

MySQL data.

```
id  pid aid
1   2   3
2   3   2
3   3   4
```

MySQL table.

```
CREATE TABLE ab ( 
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
pid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
aid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  
PRIMARY KEY (id), 
UNIQUE KEY (pid, aid)
);
```

Comment: That depends on what you need it to do, which you haven't provided any detail about.

Comment: @OMG Ponies what do you mean?

Comment: Elaborate please? Unique key would ensure that the values inserted are always unique (no duplicates are allowed).

Comment: So my UNIQUE Key is wrong for my data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unique index you have created is a valid index. It creates an index which allows duplicate values in `pid` and also in `aid` but does not allow duplicates of any pair `(pid, aid)`. For example, this insert would fail if your table already contains the data from your example because it conflicts with the second row:

```
INSERT INTO ab (pid, aid) VALUES (3, 2)
```

Comment: if i have the number 3 for both pid and aid is that valid?

Comment: can I have both aid and pid with the same values only once on the same row to be clear.

Comment: @slang: Yes, you can try `INSERT INTO ab (pid, aid) VALUES (3, 3)`.  This will work the first time - but if you try it twice it will fail the second time.